# Proof of halting problem

Tags: halting-problem

if we change the halts to do_not_halt() function, it works, so how can this be a proof?

```
def g():
    if halts(g):
        loop_forever()
```

if we change the halts to do_not_halt() function, it works, so how can this be a proof?

Comment: The function `halts()` does not change. You created a program wrapped around it, using `halts()` only as a subroutine within the `if` statement.

Comment: i am saying if we change the halts to do_not_halt() function, now the do_not_halt function will correctly say if a function will halt or not

Comment: Just showing a small sample of some proof is not enough information. Do not assume that we are presently reading the same material as you. Also "it works" is completely meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood the proof strategy for the undecidability of the halting problem.

The proof goes as follows:

- Suppose towards a contradiction that there is some magic computable function `halts(x)` that takes as input a (description of an) algorithm $x$ and returns true if $x()$ halts and false otherwise.
- Then you can define a function `g`  that uses `halt` as a subroutine as in your question.
- If `g()` halts, then `halt(g)` must return false, which contradicts the correctness of `halt`. If `g()` does not halt, then `halt(g)` must return true, which is again a contradiction.
- Since we always reach a contradiction, our hypothesis cannot be true. I.e., there is no computable function that decides whether an input function halts.

If you replace `halts(x)` with another function `does_not_halt(x)` that returns true if and only if `x()` runs forever, then you won't be able to derive a contradiction using the above proof. This *does not mean that there is no proof* that the halting problem is undecidable, just that the above proof attempt is not a good one.

In fact, you can show that no computable function `does_not_halt(x)` can exist with a minor modification of the above proof. Consider the following function `h`:

```
h():
   if not does_not_halt(h):
       loop forever
```

and examine what happens when `h()` is run. If `h()` halts, then the condition in the `if` statement must be false, i.e., `does_not_halt(h)` must return true. If `h()` does not halt, then the condition in the `if` statement must be true, i.e., `does_not_halt(h)` must return false. This leads to a contradiction in either case.

Answer (score 1):

```
def g():
    if does_not_halt(g):
        loop_forever()
```

defines a function `g` that halts if `g` is proven to halt and does not halt if `g` is proven not to halt. This says nothing about the existence of `g` and does not help us.

The original `g`, on the opposite

```
def g():
    if halts(g):
        loop_forever()
```

cannot exist as its definition is contradictory (`g` does not halt if `g` is proven to halt and halts if `g` is proven not to halt!), and this proves the theorem.